# intercell interference

Tags: matlab

Hij Vi Si the Desired signal
∑_(j=1, j≠i) Interfering signals

how can I model interference?
[image: how can I model this interference that occurs as a result of interference from neighboring cells??]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can I model this equation in Matlab. How are these variables and arrays defined in MATLAB? I need help please

Comment: I believe you should state the problem more clearly and in addition provide some more information as to what is what. What is $CUE_{i}$, $BS_{i}$, etc. There's not much people can help with if you don't state the problem crearly.